# Serving functions and database in firebase at the same time

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

When running `firebase serve --port 9000` I serve my firebase app but the console message ends with

```
Ignoring trigger "onJobWrite" because the Realtime Database emulator is not running.
```

I can run `firebase emulators:start --only database` to get the emulator up and running manually but it doesn't seem to work to run it separately.

As far as I can see the function I'm running is not the local one but the one in the cloud and that's not what I want as my trigger is local.

What can I do to make the database trigger the database locally?